# How to import svg-to-pdfkit into a reactjs project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, pdf-generation

I found a library that may solve a problem I have, which is to export an SVG drawing to a PDF document, the lib in questions can be found here [svg-to-pdfkit](https://github.com/alafr/SVG-to-PDFKit)

The problem I have is that I dont know how to import the lib into my reactjs project, any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need to import the package? So you can use it? If so I believe:

```
const SVGtoPDF = require('svg-to-pdfkit');
```

Now you can access:

```
SVGtoPDF(document, svg, 0, 0)
```